# npyscreen and threading : change form in an other thread

Tags: python, multithreading

So here we go. I am working on a funny project that purpose a login interface (standard username/password input) :

```
class LoginDisplay(npyscreen.Form):

    def create(self):
        self.name = Config.welcome_message
        self.wgUsername = self.add(npyscreen.TitleText, name="Username :")
        self.wgPassword = self.add(TitlePassword, name="Password :")

    def beforeEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.unlog_user()
        self.wgUsername.value = ""
        self.wgPassword.value = ""

    def afterEditing(self):
        self.parentApp.log_user(self.wgUsername.value, self.wgPassword.value)
```

Sounds cool, work fine.

My issue is that I am working on an other way to login using an NFC reader. The code is kind of simple :

```
def badge(myApp):
    """ Target function of a Thread """
    device = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0',timeout=60)
    device.setTimeout(1)
    buff = ''
    while myApp.isAlive: 
        s = device.read(1)
        if s == '':
            sleep(1)
        elif s == '\r' :
            # buff var containing the badge id
            myApp.login_by_badge(buff)
        else:
            buff = buff + s
```

So the objective is, if the login is correct, to change the current form (the current form) like this :

```
class MyApplication(npyscreen.NPSAppManaged):

     # .../...

     def log_user(self, username, password):
         if self._valid_login(username, password):
             self.switchForm("ANOTHER_FORM")

     def login_by_badge(self, badge_id):
         if self._valid_badge(badge_id):
             self.switchForm("ANOTHER_FORM")
```

Of course, switching forms in the sub-thread does. I look deep in the sources, and it looks like the library `npyscreen` is absolutely not designed for this kind of things.

**Question**: Should I implement my owns windgets, forms and parts of my application to manage this, or is there a common way to deal with threads interactions in `npyscreen` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the author of npyscreen.

You should look in to using the event system that was added in the most recent versions.  I added that in part to allow you to send messages between threads.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! I found a turnaround for my case based on the `while_editting` and `while_waiting` functions. Here is the snippet of my form : http://gitlab.air-eisti.fr/snippets/3 Is it what you are speaking about ?